# How to convert Hours to days - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

If i have a start time and a finish time, and i am finding the total time, if this goes above 24 hours, i wish for it instead of showing 26, to show 1 day and 2 hours. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you trying to do this SQL side?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to do an

```
IF    (MOD(HOUR(TIME) / 24) )  > 24, 
    SELECT CONCAT(
    FLOOR(HOUR(TIME) / 24), ' days ',
    MOD(HOUR(TIME), 24), ' hours ',
    MINUTE(TIME), ' minutes')
)
```

With `Timediff`,

```
FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2010-01-06 08:46', '2010-01-01 12:30')) / 24), ' days ',
```

Comment: I could not get this to work.  mysql 5.6.   The mod function uses comma (,) separator and not (/).  There is no ELSE clause to the IF.

Answer (score 0):

If your `start_time` and `end_time` are datetime type then use [**TIMEDIFF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)  function and apply the desired DATE_FORMAT.

e.g.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF('2012:01:01 00:00:00', '2012:01:01 00:00:00.000001'),
                  '%d: %H: %m');
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
select
   o.id,
   o.created,
   o.complete_date,
   concat(timestampdiff(day, o.created, o.complete_date),
          'd ',
          lpad(
             mod(timestampdiff(hour, o.created, o.complete_date), 24),
             2, '0'),
          'h'
   ) as time_to_complete,
from
   orders o
;
```

Results:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id      | created             | complete_date       | time_to_complete |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 2393721 | 2018-02-20 00:01:44 | 2018-02-21 02:32:08 | 1d 02h           |
| 2393722 | 2018-02-20 00:02:56 | 2018-02-21 00:32:08 | 1d 00h           |
| 2393723 | 2018-02-20 00:04:12 | 2018-02-20 21:32:07 | 0d 21h           |
| 2393724 | 2018-02-20 00:04:50 | 2018-02-20 23:47:05 | 0d 23h           |
| 2393725 | 2018-02-20 00:07:07 | 2018-02-20 17:32:03 | 0d 17h           |
| 2393726 | 2018-02-20 00:13:41 | 2018-02-21 00:32:08 | 1d 00h           |
| 2393727 | 2018-02-20 00:14:25 | 2018-02-21 00:32:08 | 1d 00h           |
| 2393728 | 2018-02-20 00:16:47 | 2018-02-20 23:32:04 | 0d 23h           |
| 2393729 | 2018-02-20 00:17:19 | 2018-02-20 23:47:09 | 0d 23h           |
| 2393730 | 2018-02-20 00:17:59 | 2018-02-21 01:32:08 | 1d 01h           |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```